# SSIS csv gets loaded into one column rather than different columns

Tags: ssis

When I try to establish a flat file conncetion using column and row delimiters. They are `,` and `CR-LF` as follows. I review it, I see all the values of csv file in one column.

How to separate it into different columns?  Being new, just a hint would work for me.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us something, e.g. a **screenshot** of how you're trying to import the CSV, or something else that would enable us to help you?? ...

Comment: when I open my csv with notepad++ I see the columns as Model_dscNull,Model_CDNull,DescriptionCRLF Values Landrover,NullD2Null,NullW5mce and I just saw all the values are being imported to 1 column in flat file connection manager like Column0 has Landrover,NullD2Null,NullW5mce  . How should I separate them in different columns . I cant send you the screenshot here . I can email you if give me your email id .

Comment: I don't know how these Null are coming from

Comment: Sounds like the delimiter is not correct.  It would be helpful if you could edit your post to include a screenshot of the advanced tab of the flat file connection manager and two lines of data (header + one line data).  Obfuscate as necessary but keep the delimiters and text qualifiers the same.

Comment: Hi , can you please see now . I have added a picture as well now . PLease , its very urgent .

Comment: You are yet to show the Delimiter page, in the image it shows only Preview data tab

Comment: In your first image, the data is appearing in separate columns, so where are you seeing it all in one column?   Also why does the data connection have two different names in your two screenshots?

Comment: yes , tab here data is coming in separate columns when I changed the delimiter to comma and CR-LF  but when I execute the package only Model_Dsc gets populated not the other columns so I am assuming there is some problem in my flat file connection . I have added one more screenshot that shows data in sql server .Also that was my bad , data conncetion name . i used the same connections later . Its just that i have been trying a lot of things . but the connections look fine . rets assured .

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "when I execute the package only".   It sounds like maybe you haven't uploaded the latest version of your package to the ssis server, because the one in your screenshots should work.   On a side note, @Ritu I see you have asked 10 questions recently, and you have not accepted a single answer on any of them.   People in this community will be more inclined to help you if you follow up on your questions and accept the answers that helped you.   It will also increase your reputation when you do so.

Comment: Thanks Tab , will do so accepting answers . Its not to hurt anyone but just new to the forum . i will try uploading the latest versions and come back .

Comment: I appreciate everyone for helping me out . Can you please see the latest picture for more information